# How to best separate password "tiers" or not at all?

Tags: password-management

While using a password<sup>+</sup> manager is a know must for sensible security, one nuisance (from an UX point of view) I encounter is that there are different password "tiers". Pretty obviously my e.g. file encryption and online banking access must be as secure as (reasonably) possible and it's okay having to enter a complex passphrase first since banking is a task worth 100% attention, done in a trustworthy environment only etc. But on the other end there's e.g. forums - services where authentication is sensible as well, but maybe used more often also in public environments. That is something in my mind not "worth" unlocking the entire password vault (also from a paranoid point of view), yet I don't want to reuse my "s<s>h---y</s>imple forum password" all the time. Thus there are different tiers of passwords, and I'm still not sure how to properly treat them. Possibilities are:

- Use a single password manager's vault anyway. Pro: simple, contra: more possible exposition of all sensitive data due to more often using the manger even for low-tier access, and due to the required security can become quite tedious
- use a password manager only for high-tier passphrases, and an insecure method for low-tier ones (though hopefully at least more thoughtful than pure reuse)
- use multiple vaults, so the high-tier one remains locked even when accessing the low-tier passwords. Not sure how well common password managers can cope with that, or at least I didn't find the proper term to search for

Are there other sensible solutions? Or am I overthinking this and shouldn't make a difference between those tiers at all period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to think about this is with a threat model.

You've got a set of assets to protect. Those assets can be roughly grouped into two levels of risk. Risk is calculated by the likelihood of an attacker going after that asset, multiplied by the impact or cost that would occur if they compromised that asset.

You access those assets from your computer, which is a trusted device. If an attacker compromises your computer, they inherently have access to the assets you access. If you place your passwords in a password manager, and that password manager is only unlocked on your computer, everything remains at the same trust level.

The two primary threats you are concerned about are:

1. in the event an attacker gains access to your computer with the password manager unlocked, they can quickly gain access to assets that are in the high risk category; and
2. in the event that an asset is compromised, weak memorised passwords that are re-used or pattern-based may be cracked and utilised to gain access to other assets.

You can evaluate each of your proposed solutions based on this scenario:

- Using multiple vaults:

  - Does not resolve the issue of vault compromise in a concrete way, since an attacker could just wait for you to open the vault.
  - Does resolve the issue of weak memorised passwords.
- Using a vault for high risk asset passwords and memorised passwords for low risk assets:

  - Actually provides better security for the low risk passwords than the high risk passwords in the vault compromise scenario.
  - Does not resolve the issue of weak memorised passwords.
- Using a single password manager:

  - Does not resolve the issue of vault compromise.
  - Does resolve the issue of weak memorised passwords.

The third solution offers the greatest risk reduction for the least day-to-day overhead. However, it leaves you right where you started, without any additional security for high risk assets. It is clear that none of these proposed solutions offer sufficient risk reduction in relation to your threat model.

What you need are *compensating controls* for the high risk assets. In this case, two-factor authentication (2FA) is a good primary candidate. It offers meaningful risk reduction for high risk assets without imposing any additional work when accessing low risk assets. An attacker who compromises your password vault cannot access assets with 2FA enabled. However, you must take care to place any 2FA recovery codes or soft tokens in a separate control sphere from your computer, so that an attacker who gains access to it cannot access those resources and defeat 2FA.

For assets that cannot support 2FA, other compensating controls that minimise the impact of an attack, reduce the likelihood of attack, and/or alert you to potential security incidents should be considered. Those are likely to be specific to the asset in question, but you should evaluate them against the same criteria shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly a valid approach to take - there was a good Microsoft whitepaper once making exactly this point - but my own feeling is that it is a waste of mental bandwith trying to decide how important a site is, and then later remembering how you signed in to it.

I use my password manager for everything and 99% of the time it pastes the password in for me and no further effort required. The other 1% of the time, since I've now fully moved to diceware style passphrases, it's still easy to type.

(I suppose if I think something is especially sensitive I might add another word to the passphrase...)

(And of course use multi-factor everywhere!)